# Por qué un arreglo de doubles inicializado marca un nullPointer?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, método, map, nullpointerexception

El siguiente codigo no marca errores de compilación, pero cuando mando a llamar al método `darDeAlta()` e introduzco datos, me marca el siguiente error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` en la linea `d[i] = y.nextDouble();` (dentro del método) y en la línea `bandera = e.darDeAlta();` (dentro del main), ya inicialize el arreglo de doubles con `null` y no entiendo porque me marca ese error.

```
public class Ejercicio {

Map<Integer, Alumno> alumnos = new TreeMap<>();

public boolean darDeAlta() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b = false;
    double d[] = null;

    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del estudiante");
    String n = y.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su matricula (de 5 digitos)");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca las calificaciones: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
        d[i] = y.nextDouble();//marca error aqui

    }

    if (alumnos.containsKey(m)) {
        System.out.println("Esa matricula ya existe, ingrese otra matricula");

    } else {
        alumnos.put(m, new Alumno(n, m, d));
        System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");
        System.out.println("Desea ingresar mas alumnos?");
        String s = y.nextLine();
        if (s.equals("si")) {
            b = true;
        } else {
            b = false;
        }
    }
    return b;

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bandera = false;

    Ejercicio e = new Ejercicio();

    do {

        System.out.println("[a]ltas" + "\n" + "[b]ajas" + "\n" + "[c]onsultas" + "\n" + "[m]odificaciones" + "\n" + "[s]alir");
        System.out.println("\n Seleccione una opcion");
        String opcion = x.next();
        if (opcion.compareTo("a") == 0) {
            bandera = e.darDeAlta();//marca error aqui
        }
        if (opcion.compareTo("b") == 0) {
            e.darDeBaja();
            if (opcion.compareTo("c") == 0) {
                e.consultas();
                if (opcion.compareTo("m") == 0) {
                    e.modificaciones();
                    if (opcion.compareTo("s") == 0) {
                        bandera = false;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (bandera);
}

}
```

Comment: Hay un error porque lo inicializas a `null`.... revisa cómo se instancia un array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No haz inicializado el objeto `d[]`:

```
double d[] = null;
```

Debes de inicializarlo:

```
double d[] = new double[5];
```

Comment: aah ya, ya se corrigio el error